# Why using Spring DM?

Tags: spring, esb, spring-dm

1/ did Spring DM is very used now on Enterprise Applications ? what are the benefits of this framework and why it seem like a dead technology

2/ I'm working on a Spring Application , I want to do it as an SOA and i don't know if spring DM will be useful for me.

3/ I have another question , we can integrate an open source solution ESB with Spring ? what's the best choice for ESB.

Thanks !

Comment: This question as written is too vague and based in opinion. If you decide on Spring DM and come across particular implementation issues, we can help with that if you show us your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Spring DM is mostly abandoned by Spring, as well as OSGI support. See this key quote from the Spring creator in this important [interview](http://www.theserverside.com/news/2240037102/OSGi-Not-Easy-Enough-to-Use-Not-as-Productive-as-it-Should-Be) on the subject:

> We have changed our views on OSGi over the years, and one of the
>   reasons for that is that OSGi simply cannot be made as easy to use and
>   as productive as we feel is consistent with Spring values.

See also [SpringFramework Removes OSGi Metadata in Move to Gradle](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/10/spring-osgi-gradle/)

2) and 3) try to use [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) or [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/), which is well integrated with Spring. Both allow to have ESB like functionality embedded in a normal WAR application, so no need for a separate ESB server.